# Fixed size bootstrap panel with flex content and header

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The panel height is fixed at 300px, the header and content might change but the footer should stay fixed at the buttom.

What is the best way to achieve this ?

Setting

```
.panel { 
   height : 250px;
}

.panel .panel-footer { 
 position : absolute;
 bottom : 0;        
}
```

Cause the footer to slightly slide outside the border of the panel and to lose width.
I'm trying to find a solution with as little fixed sizing as possible.

[Bootply example here](http://www.bootply.com/126471)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this solution may help you

http://www.bootply.com/giovapanasiti/126477

Comment: I took you'r idea of using a table and just made my own version of the panel. Thanks man. [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/126954)

Answer (score 1):

Good day!

the panel slides out because it's wrapper has margin-bottom wich bottom: 0 does not account for.

A simple solution wold be to apply this css:

```
.panel {
    height : 250px;
    margin-bottom:0;
    position: relative;
}

.panel .panel-footer {
    position : absolute;
    bottom : 0;
    margin-bottom:1px;
    width : 100%;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/126692

Comment: Sorry, i thought the div sliding out was the problem, updated my answer so it works when resized.